# haproxy how to decode the URL when proxying the request

Tags: haproxy

I have a URL (encoded) something like below:

```
http://localhost:8080/download?a=123&b=2.3%2B140
```

and my task is to proxy this request to some other server. While I am doing so in haproxy I'm extracting URL parameters of the original URL to be in the proxy destination url like below:

```
http://destination.com/%[urlp(a)]/%[urlp(b)]
```

now this URL gives me 400 because b is in encoded format and in order to make the destination URL work I need to get it decoded...

Any ways to decode the URL parameter before setting it in haproxy?

I tried below but didn't work:

```
http-request set-query %[query,regsub(%2B,+,g)]
```

Comment: I don't think you are necessarily identifying the problem.  `400 Bad Request` *should* mean the request is syntactically invalid, and it is impossible for  url-encoding in the path to make a request syntactically invalid.  Semantically, yes, but syntactically, no. Not all servers honor this, but it is the standard.  Please show your actual configuration that cause 400 Bad Request -- the relevant parts -- and an example of actual query parameters.  If you are using `req[i]rep`, it's very easy to break the protocol with an error on your rules, which would then certainly cause an unrelated 400.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I figured out i was not appending / in set-path configuration thus making it 400. now its working fine.